# SharePoint 2013 masterpage editing - Windows cannot access http://<myserver>/_catalogs/masterpage/"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to map the SharePoint 2013 masterpage library as a network drive so that I can do some masterpage manipulations. Unfortunately I am getting an error as below.

> Windows cannot access `http://<myserver>/_catalogs/masterpage/`

I am running Windows Server 2008 R2. I confirmed that I have Desktop Experience feature activated and the WebClient service is started on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved.

I just installed **MS Office 2010 Premium** on the server and now I can map the folder as a drive as well as the *open with explorer* is also working! (btw, I am doing developement from within that server. I am not accessing sharepoint sites from a local system for now).

To make WebDAV authoring, why I need MS office on on my local machine (and in server if the map ad drive / open with explorer is done there)? I am not sure about this. Anybody know why is like that?

Community, thank you for all your suggestion

---

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try it in the browser. `e.g. http://yourdomainname/sites/yoursite/_catalogs/masterpage/Forms/AllItems.aspx`

To map it, use the **full path** and follow the instructions given [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj733519%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Comment: HI Markus, Thank you for your reply. In fact I am following same steps and there I am seeing the mapping error. On the browser the url is opening (even without .../forms/allitems.aspx") the page.

Comment: @Arun: and `\\yourdomain\sites\yoursite\_catalogs\masterpage` is not working in the (File-) Explorer?

Comment: No Markus, its not working.

Comment: Any help to solve the issue?